# Does 1 year old user receive yearling badge immediately after reaching 200 reputation?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges, yearling-badge

Today I have 317 reputation and I am member for 1 year and 11 months (since 2009-04-02). But I still didn't receive yearling badge.

Is there anything else taken into account for **yearling badge**? Or is it bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had read somewhere on meta. The reputation is calculated at the end of each year. i.e. When you crossed one year, you did not have enough reputation hence you did not get the badge. Now it will calculate for your second year. In second year, you should actually have 400 reputation points to get this badge. Else you wont get it.

its calculated as `reputation > (years * 200)`, then only you get the yearling badge.

Comment: Verified and accepted.Now as I reached 402 reputation I become the yearling badge. To be more exact, I received 2 yearling badges at once.

Comment: If I have over 2k reputation does that mean, I will have 10 yearling badge in 10 years even if do nothing for the next 10 years ?

Comment: @Myself - Yes. As far as I know, that is correct.

Answer (score 5):

There is a case where you get the badge after the first year but before the second.

If you reach 300+ reputation after 18 months you will get the badge as:

> reputation > years * 200 where years = 1.5

As:

> 1.5 * 200 = 300